# Taking last word of an string, variable not declared?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, split

I am taking a cell value (sometimes is "flores", sometimes "de las flores"), but I cannot really know the value since there are 10000+ records.

What I want to do is take just "flores" (the last word, and if there is only one, well then, that one). Ive tried using split and then ubound, but I get a "not declared" error. But i am trying to make it implicit.

```
Function CheckFirstLetter(mystring, text, indexCurp, index) As Boolean
            Dim outStr, asciinum, vocal As String, i As Long
---->            arr = Split(mystring, " ")
---->            vocal = arr(UBound(ary))
            outStr = LCase(Mid(text, indexCurp, 1))
            asciinum = LCase(Mid(mystring, 1, 1))
            Cells(index, "M") = vocal
            Cells(index, "O") = asciinum
            If (asciinum = outStr) Then
                CheckFirstLetter = True
                Else: CheckFirstLetter = False
                End If
End Function
```

Thanks!

Comment: Will you rephrase your question please? It's not clear, at least to me?

Comment: Kudos for using `Option Explicit` to tell you about typos. Next step, fix the typos. `ary` isn't `arr`. And where's `arr` declared anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are overly complicating it anyway.  Unless I'm reading it wrong (very possible) you can simplify this A LOT.

```
Function CheckFirstLetter(mystring, text, indexCurp, index) As Boolean
    Dim vocal() As String

    vocal = Split(mystring, " ")

    Cells(index, "M") = vocal(UBound(vocal))
    Cells(index, "O") = LCase(Mid(mystring, 1, 1))

    CheckFirstLetter = Cells(index, "O") = LCase(Mid(text, indexCurp, 1))

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

"Variable not declared" is a compile-time error, which indicates that you have `Option Explicit` specified - and that's an **excellent** thing, *do not remove it!*

> *But i am trying to make it implicit.*

There is no reason to ever want to do that.

`Option Explicit` **requires** variable declaration. So you **must** declare all variables you use.

If you want an implicit *type* for a variable, declare it without an `As` clause:

```
Dim arr ' implicit: As Variant
```

I suspect `ary` is a typo here:

```
vocal = arr(UBound(ary))
```

If that's meant to get the item at the upper bound of `arr`, then `ary` should be `arr`.

---

This is redundant:

```
If (asciinum = outStr) Then
    CheckFirstLetter = True
    Else: CheckFirstLetter = False
    End If
```

Could be written as a simple assignment:

```
CheckFirstLetter = (asciinum = outStr)
```

---

Your code is very much implicit already. These two instructions implicitly refer to the `ActiveSheet`:

```
Cells(index, "M") = vocal
Cells(index, "O") = asciinum
```

These declarations declare `outStr` and `asciinum` as implicit `Variant`:

```
Dim outStr [As String], asciinum [As String], vocal As String, i As Long
```

The parameters are all implicitly passed `ByRef` (`ByVal` would be sufficient), and they're all implicit `Variant` as well:

```
mystring, text, indexCurp, index
```

VS

```
ByVal mystring As String, ByVal text As String, ByVal indexCurp As Long, ByVal index As Long
```

And these function calls return a `Variant`, which means an implicit convertion to `String` if `outStr` and `asciinum` are strings:

```
outStr = LCase(Mid(text, indexCurp, 1))
asciinum = LCase(Mid(mystring, 1, 1))
```

These would return a `String` instead:

```
outStr = LCase$(Mid$(text, indexCurp, 1))
asciinum = LCase$(Mid$(mystring, 1, 1))
```

See, your code has more than enough implicit-ness already. No need for implicit variables on top of that! Kudos for:

- Using Option Explicit
- Returning an explicit `Boolean`
- Using `PascalCase` for naming your function